# Number of different partial derivatives of a given function

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Consider a function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ of $n$ variables. How many different partial derivatives of order $r$ does $f$ possess?

The above problem was obtained from Sheldon Ross's "A first course in probability". I believe the answer should be $n^r$ partial derivatives, since there are $n$ choices for each independent variable as we differentiate successively from the $1$st to the $r$th derivative. However, I would like to verify this answer. I would also appreciate an alternative approach to the problem.

I found out that this problem is similar to the one solved here: [How many n-th Order Partial Derivatives Exist for a Function of k Variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1710875/how-many-n-th-order-partial-derivatives-exist-for-a-function-of-k-variables)

However, the accepted solution in the link above was based on the assumption that the order of differentiation does not matter. I believe this is only true when the given function is smooth (we weren't told it is). Even if we agree that the function is indeed smooth, isn't the answer supposed to be $n^r / r! $, given that we are considering the $r$th partial derivatives with distinct sets of independent variables only?

Comment: $n^r$ is too many, since $\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}$ would be double-counted.

Comment: Hint. If the function is smooth enough the order in which you take the derivatives does not matter.

Comment: Did you try for $n=1,2,3?$

Comment: Doesn't the answer depend on $f$? For example, if $f$ is a polynomial then for large enough $r$ all partial derivatives will be the same zero function.

Comment: We weren't told the function is smooth, so we cannot assume the equivalence of second order partial-derivatives @Ethan Bolker

Comment: @Mark Good point, but I believe the problem has a single solution.

Comment: When the $n$th partial derivatives all exist there's some implicit smoothness about the $k$th derivatives for $k < n$. I don't know just what that is, but I suspect it's more subtle than Ross expected you to know of derive. I think that the linked answer, which relies on the formal structure, is what was intended. And thanks to @Mark 's comment, you really do want to think about the formal differentiation operators, not their effect on particular functions.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes I understand, thanks for the insight. But why is $ n^r / r! $ not correct?

Comment: @Toba Because there are $3! = 6$ rearrangements of $xyz$ but it's subtler to count the rearrangements of things like $xxy$.